# Delay in writing values to CSV using FasterCSV gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fastercsv

I'm reading values from one csv file using FasterCSV gem and doing some operations and dumping the same data to a different csv file by adding one additional column which specifies the status of the each row.
Below is the code for the same

```
   path ="#{RAILS_ROOT}/data/reports/file1.csv"
   output_path = "#{RAILS_ROOT}/data/reports/file2.csv"
   FasterCSV.open(output_path, "w") do |csv|
   FasterCSV.foreach(path,:headers => false) do |row|
      if self.import_file_has_header == true
        if starting_row == 0
          row << "Status"
          csv << row
          starting_row = starting_row + 1
          next
         end
      end
     ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
       # doing some operations 
      end
     row << "Success"
      csv << row
     end
   end
```

even the operations were successful in a transaction, there was a delay in dumping data ,this one observed when downloaded the file, which shows 0 MB  at begining after some time size of the file is growing and for some time it will be of same size and the process will be continued. Is there any reason for this or am I doing anything wrong ?

I am using ruby 1.8.7 and fastercsv (1.5.4).

Comment: Benchmark the database transaction? _Sidenote:_ why on the Earth do you use ruby 1.8.7 which is even not legacy: it’s ancient.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @mudasobwa. We are working on a very old application, it's very difficult to transit from ruby 1.8.7 to higher version.  Can you please briefly explain how benchmarking database transaction will help us?

Comment: You might make it clean that the time is spent in database operations.